# What is the error in my own PHP regex code?

Tags: php, regex, string

Today, I have read a question on Stack Overflow, at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151810/how-to-parse-this-text-block-into-variables-by-php

I have tried to do it with this code:

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z_]+)/", "[first_text] = [second_text, third_text] : [forth_text, fifth_text]", $matches);
```

When I tested it, it didn't work correctly:

```
echo $matches[0];
echo $matches[1];
echo $matches[2];
echo $matches[3];
echo $matches[4];
```

Will print:

```
first_textfirst_text
```

What is the error in my own PHP regex code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z_]+)/', "[first_text] = [second_text, third_text] : [forth_text, fifth_text]", $matches);
```

[`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will return all the matches using your regex whereas `preg_match` just gives you first match.